GraalVM native not loading a configuration class in Quarkus
I'm working on a aws lambda using Quarkus.
I'm trying to load a custom class to configure my database connection in a custom way.
I wrote the following class, that works perfectly when I run locally (not native):
@PersistenceUnitExtension
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterForReflection
public class OracleDatasourceConfig implements TenantConnectionResolver {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url")
    String connectionStringProperty;

    private final KeyVaultConfig keyVaultConfig;

    public OracleDatasourceConfig(KeyVaultConfig keyVaultConfig) {
        this.keyVaultConfig = keyVaultConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectionProvider resolve(String tenantId) {
        try {

            // configurations and code...

            return new QuarkusConnectionProvider(AgroalDataSource.from(new AgroalPropertiesReader()
                .readProperties(properties)
                .get()));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}

This class loads just fine locally, but when I deploy my code on aws lambda it builds as native and my class seems to not load at all.
I'm new to graalvm and native java code, so I'm struggling to understand how to make this work.
I imagine that the problem is some reflection that native have its own way to deal with but I can't find any sources to help me out with this.
How to make sure this class will run on native?
PS:
To add more details what my code does:
I have dynamic login and password for my database so I can't configure my connection with static password and login in the application.properties file.
My class uses quarkus' TenantConnectionResolver to return a QuarkusConnectionProvider connected.
This class is a bean that quarkus load on the start of the application, so it should run without me calling it anywhere.
Locally, it works properly, but on native build this class is never load. There's no errors nor exceptions shown. Quarkus uses default connection and it fails because I don't have any password configured for it.

What issue are you seeing? Is there an exception?

There's nothing at all! No excpetions, just my class are not loaded. I added log msgs to it just to check if the class had an error but nothing is printed. Also, quarkus return to default database connection because my custom connection is not beeing loaded.
